# Kähler differentials on a smooth projective plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, coherent-sheaves

Let $C = \{f=0\} \subset \mathbb{P}_k^2$ be a smooth plane curve of degree $d$.

I'm trying to find an explicit basis for $H^0(C,\Omega^1_{C/k})$. I know it should be $\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$ - dimensional. What I'm trying to find is an explicit collection of rational 1-forms on $C$ (basically elements in $k(C) \large{\frac{dx}{\partial_y f}}$) which when restricted to $C$ give a basis for all 1-forms. Sadly most of what I tried didn't get me anywhere and so I have no interesting attempts to share. Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any particular cases? For example, do you see why if $f=y^2z-x^3-Axz^2-Bz^3$ then a basis is given by the 'invariant differential' $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{y}$? I haven't truthfully thought about if it's easier than this, but one natural way to do this would be the following. One can easily write down a basis of $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)$ by using the explicit nature of the isomorphism $\displaystyle H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)=k^{N}$ where $N=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$ which comes from the SES $0\to \mathcal{O}(-d)\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}\to i_\ast\mathcal{O}_C\to 0$ and the e

Comment: explicit nature of $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}(-d))$ (which is computed explicitly, in terms of Cech cocycles, in Hartshorne for example). One can then obtain an explicit basis for $H^0(C,\omega_C)$ by thinking about the explicit form of Serre duality on a curve. This seems overkill to me (it's possible that one can just 'do it by hand' as in the case of elliptic curves) but it certainly will work.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Actually I did try to use the conormal sequence $$0 \to \mathcal{O}_V(-d) \to \mathcal{O}_{V}(-3 )\to \Omega^1_V \to 0$$ which gives me the immpresion that an explicit discription would be $p \frac{dx}{\partial_y f}$ with $p$ a polynomial of degree at most $d-3$. I'm not so sure how to make this precise though...

Comment: Well, since we're working with a divisor (let's assume, as you probably were, that $f$ is irreducible) the adjunction formula gives us that $\omega_C=i^\ast(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}((-3-d))$ where $i:C\to\mathbb{P}^2$. But, this is still a little bit worrying (in the sense of getting something explicit) since we really want to calculate $H^0(C,\omega_C)$ and obviously knowing what $\omega_C=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-d-3)\mid_C$ is helpful for this, but doesn't do it the full way (unless I'm being silly). Again, it seems like the natural thing to do would be to trace through

Comment: Riemann-Roch (which is how one would use this to get just $h^0(C,\omega_C)$) and see how explicit you can make it. I don't see any really obvious way to make this explicit in that case. I apologize if I'm being dense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the basis explicitly you can use the Poincare residue map
$$
\text{res}: H^0(\mathbb{P}^2, \Omega^2_{\mathbb{P}^2}(C)) \to H^0(C, \Omega^1_C),
$$
which in this case is an isomorphism.

Let $g(x_1, x_2) = f(1,x_1,x_2)$, any 2-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ with a single pole along $C$ can be written locally in coordinates $x_1$, $x_2$ as
$$
\omega = t(x_1, t_2) \frac{dx_1 \wedge dx_2}{g(x_1,x_2)},
$$
then the residue of $\omega$ is 
$$
\text{res}(\omega) = t(x_1, x_2) \frac{dx_2}{g_{x_1}(x_1,x_2)}.
$$

Section $dx_1 \wedge dx_2$ has a pole of order 3 on the hyperplane $H$ at infinity ($K_{\mathbb{P}^2} = -3H$), and $f$ has a pole of order $d$ along $H$, so $\omega$ is holomorphic when $t$ is a rational function with a possible pole of order $\leq d-3$ along $H$, such functions are polynomials in $x_1$ and $x_2$ of order $\leq d-3$. There are $l+1$ monomials of degree $l$ in two variables, so there are $\sum_{l=0}^{d-3} (l+1)=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$ monomials of degree $\leq d-3$. The explicit basis of $H^0(C, \Omega^1_C)$ is given by residues of $\omega$'s with all monomials of such degrees.